# Building a Volume Shadow Service app for release

Tags: c++, c, winapi, com, volume-shadow-service

How should an application that uses the Volume Shadow Copy service be built for release? I've been building and testing in Windows 7 and everything looks good so I built the app to test in Windows XP and I get an error on startup:

```
The procedure entry point VssFreeSnapshotPropertiesInternal could not be located in the dynamic link library VSSAPI.DLL
```

Now, I realise that a way round this is to use `LoadLibrary` and call the function if it exists but surely the function should exist in the first place to be able to use VSS?

I read somewhere that I would need to build a different version for XP, Server 2003, Windows 7 etc but I've not seen that in other applications that use VSS.

What is the correct way to build a VSS app?

Thanks,
J

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at HoboCopy source code.
This should answer every question you could have.
It's free (for personal use) and C++ src code covers all Windows versions from XP to 2008.
Src has moved, anyway start from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wangdera/files/HoboCopy/1.0.0.0/).

Comment: Thanks for the link. I think that answers my question right away with the different binaries for each platform. Thanks, J.

Answer (score 1):

Note: The Windows SDK can be used to develop VSS applications only for Windows Vista and later Windows operating system versions. It cannot be used to develop VSS requester's, providers, or writers for Windows Server 2003 R2, Windows Server 2003, or Windows XP.

link: [VSS Application Compatibility (Windows)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384627%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)